# How to use component variable within css / style tag in Angular 2?

Tags: css, angular

**How can I use component variables within style TAG in Angular 2?**

I do have an Angular 2 component for my header which I like to color depending on a users setting. Thus I'd like to assign an background and font color. While I know how to to this with an attribute binding to an element, I couldn't figure out how to use in a style tag.

Using attribute binding for style works well, however this gets pretty anoying for several subelements, especially if they are nested within other sub components. [ngStyle]= attribute is also only working on a single element.

```
<header id="header" [style.background-color]="changeBackground()">
  <div>
    Some Text
    <a href="asdf">Some Link</a>
    <subcomponent></subcomponent>
  </div>
  <div> ... a lot mor stuff </div>
</header>
```

Thus I'd like to add something like

```
<style>
#header, #header a {
  color: {{mycolor}};
}
</style>
```

to the html template. However this is not working

Similar Questions do not answer this question yet and only show attribute binding as a solution:

- [Angular2 dynamic change CSS property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33328347/angular2-dynamic-change-css-property)
- [Dynamically updating css in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35882670/dynamically-updating-css-in-angular-2)
- https://scotch.io/tutorials/all-the-ways-to-add-css-to-angular-2-components
- https://coryrylan.com/blog/introduction-to-angular-2-ngclass-and-ngstyle

Comment: `#header, #header a {` is a CSS selector that selects the element with the id `header` and it's child `<a>` element. I wouldn't expect template variable to work within style tags. You should rather use `ngStyle`. Also binding to methods in the view `="changeBackground()"` is discouraged because it is called for every change detection cycle. Rather assign the result to a property and bind the view to the property instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 dynamic change CSS property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33328347/angular2-dynamic-change-css-property)

Comment: I know this question is a bit old now, but this answer might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/48265526/1389807

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you are just creating a new component called 'subcomponent', why not do that?

subcomponent.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'subcomponent',
  templateUrl: './subcomponent.html',
})
export class SubComponent {
  mycolor = 'blue';
}
```

subcomponent.html:

```
<style>
#header, #header a {
  color: {{mycolor}};
}
</style>
```

Comment: Was my first thought too, but this is not working either. Angular extracts the style tag, inserts it into head and does not replace mustache variables in this part. :(

Comment: Check out this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830296/, it may answer why angular is moving the style tag and how to work around it.

Comment: however it still does not replace the mustache variable in my case :/

Comment: @Manuel What issues are you still facing?  Are you referring to the `{{mycolor}}` interpolation?

Comment: Yes, the HTML style block contains {{mycolor}}

Comment: And you don't want to add a style to the `<a>` tag in that template?

Comment: If i can choose, not! I'm using it in an admin theme which has a header build of several sub components. Each would have to load the data which is pretty ugly.

Comment: Have a single parent pass the data to each of the children.

Comment: Same as first answer. This is not working. It write mustache code into css which results in an invalid css property value #header[_ngcontent-mpf-4] { background-color: {{currentPartner.partnerColorPrimaryBackground}} !important; }

Comment: @manuel You're right this does not work.  I'll update this with working code.  But it won't be adding a style tag.  What you are expecting to work, is not an option.  I'll provide alternatives.

Comment: I'm experiencing this problem today. Can't believe there is still no way around it.

Answer (score -2):

To your @Component object, add

```
styles:[ `#header, #header a {
  color: {{mycolor}};
}`]
```

So for example:

```
@Component({
  template: `<header id="header" [style.background-color]="changeBackground()">
    <div>
      Some Text
      <a href="asdf">Some Link</a>
      <subcomponent></subcomponent>
    </div>
   <div> ... a lot mor stuff </div>
  </header>`,
  styles: [ `#header, #header a {
    color: {{mycolor}};
    }`
  `]
})
```

Comment: This is not working. It write mustache code into css which results in an invalid css property value `#header[_ngcontent-mpf-4] {
    background-color: {{currentPartner.partnerColorPrimaryBackground}} !important;
}`

Answer (score -3):

Use NgStyle as explained in this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41903349

in short

```
<header id="header" [ngStyle]="getStyle()">
  <div>
    Some Text
    <a href="asdf">Some Link</a>
    <subcomponent></subcomponent>
  </div>
  <div> ... a lot mor stuff </div>
</header>
```

and

```
getStyle(): any {
    return {"background-color" : this.changeBackgroundColor()};
}
```

Comment: Read the question. They do not want to use binding.