# interpolation to a css class in an external file angular 2

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular2-template

I'm wondering if is possible to pass a variable to a css class into an external css file in angular 2, like from:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
  bgc: string = 'orange'
}
```

---

then on the "app.component.css" I would like to pass like

```
.mydiv{ background: {{bgc}};  }
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this would be possible.

If you need a style to change programmatically, I would suggest looking into ngStyle at the link below:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgStyle-directive.html

Comment: Can I apply the ngStyle to the DOM, like <body [ngStyle]="{'font-style': styleExp}">?

Comment: Yes, that should be possible.

Comment: I think is not possible to add ngStyle to the <body> tag, I ran some test and didn't work

Comment: I even try the "ngStyle" with "ViewEncapsulation.None" on the component and didn't work