# Can't bind to 'display' since it isn't a known property of

Tags: angular, angular6

Suppose to have this `home.component.html` page:

```
other component
<app-modal [display]="displayModal"></app-modal>
```

Now In `my home.component.ts` I put like instance variable:

```
 @Output() displayModal='none';
```

In my `app.module.ts` do:

```
     declarations: [
        ...
        HomeComponent,
ModalComponent
        ....
      ],
```

And in my `app-modal.component.ts` I use in my instance variable:

```
 @Input() display;
```

But it gives me :

```
Can't bind to 'display' since it isn't a known property of 'app-modal'.
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 dynamic change CSS property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33328347/angular2-dynamic-change-css-property)

Comment: @Christian.K - I don't see in the question that he is trying to set a style property.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Well, the OP is trying to set something called "display" to a value of "none". That sounds suspiciously like attempting to set the CSS property of the same name. I might be wrong, but nobody has to agree with the close request anyway.

Comment: This question is confusing. Please update it to clarify what it is you're trying to do and the expected result.

Comment: I just put your example into a stackblitz, and it seems to work.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-enxkvh

Maybe you left out some other details that I missed?

I am not sure why you need to decorate the `displayModal` property of the `HomeComponent`. I assume this is a simplified example of a more complex problem you are facing.