# How to change the css class property value dynamically on angular 6?

Tags: css, angular, styles, components

I want to change the css class property value dynamically. 
On below code 'color' is the variable that I want to pass to the styles.

```
    @Component({
    selector: 'app-gridmaker-component',
    templateUrl: './gridmaker-component.component.html',
    styles: [`
    ::ng-deep .dx-datagrid .dx-row-alt > td {
        background-color: color!important;  /* color is the variable */
    }
    `]

})
```

Thanks is advance.

Comment: Wht not bind directly in HTML(template) using `ngStyle`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 dynamic change CSS property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33328347/angular2-dynamic-change-css-property)

Comment: I was looking something like this,
https://medium.com/creative-technology-concepts-code/css-in-javascript-with-angular-61da79111804